# Getting double printed rows from MySQL, native C

Tags: mysql, c

I have 2 columns that can have a value that can be in both columns but not at the same time. for exaple in the table i will show.

---

table

```
from_bank_number | to_bank_number |value

001              | 002            | 100
002              | 001            | 200
001              | 002            | 400
```

Now i will try to print this out.

```
mysql_query(conn, "SELECT from_bank_number, to_bank_number, value FROM some_table
                   WHERE from_bank_number = '001' OR to_bank_number = '001'");
res = mysql_use_result(conn);
while(row = mysql_fetch_row(res){
  printf("From: %s, To: %s, Value: %s\n",row[0], row[1], row[2]); 
}
```

This will printed out 6 times when i only have 3 rows. How do i prevent it from getting double printed?

```
From: 001, To:002, Value: 100
From: 002, To:001, Value: 200
From: 001, To:002, Value: 400
From: 001, To:002, Value: 100
From: 002, To:001, Value: 200
From: 001, To:002, Value: 400
```

i would like to get rid of duplicates

Comment: Use `select distinct ...` and if that is not ok for you - what output do you expect?

Comment: Will still get 6 outputs

Comment: Then add the expected output to your question and we will see.